# Reducing the time to convert character data to numeric data in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

In the process of solving one problem using the Newton method on python and simpi, I encountered an unpleasant circumstance.
In the problem, in symbolic form, with the help of simpi, a system of equations is generated, the number of equations depends on a certain parameter n, then the Jacobian is calculated, also in symbolic form, Then a vector of values for variables in this Jacobian is substituted into this symbolic Jacobian. The calculation of the numerical Jacobian from the symbolic Jacobian is done as follows:

```
matrix_jacobian_analitic_view=matrix_jacobian.subs(value_vector_var) .
```

In addition, for the task I made a time sensor, the results of which are recorded in pandas dataframe .
From this timer, I saw that the largest amount of time in the calculation is spent on calculating the numerical Jacobian.
Simpy will refuse this task , I can not . Therefore, I ask you to tell me a way to reduce the time for calculating the numerical Jacobian .

Comment: Looks like `matrix_jacobian` is a `sympy.expression`.  You don't show it, but I suspect it is quite large.  It's not character data, but rather a complex combination of `sympy` expressions and symbols.   In any case, there isn't much you can do to speed up `sympy` code.

Comment: @hpaulj , you are right when you say that : It's not character data, but rather a complex combination of sympy expressions and symbols

Comment: @hpaulj , what could be the ways?

Comment: If it is the the substitution of numerical values that is slow then you can use `lambdify` to speed that up.

Answer (score 0):

@hpauli and @Oscar Benjamin , Hello .
I found a way to speed up the calculation of the numerical Jacobian. Without any lambdify .
The solution is:

1. I run through each line in the symbolic Jacobian matrix , previously converted sympy matrix to numpy matrix :

   ```
   matrix_jacobian_np=np.array(matrix2numpy(matrix_jacobian)),
   ```

and then in a loop

```
    while i_jac_shape<=(matrix_jac_np.shape[0]-1):
        jac_i=matrix_jacobian[i_jac_shape,:]
        symbols_jac_i=jac_i.free_symbols
        symbols_jac_i=list(symbols_jac_i)
        index_var,symbol_list=get_symbol_in_jac(symbols_jac_i,n)
```

in the line :

```
    get_symbol_in_jac(symbols_jac_i,n)
```

I get the variable itself and the index, for example, variable T4, index =4.
having received the variable and its index , I get the value of this particular variable of the set of values for the i-th approximation ( set of values for the i-th approximation = vector_var_value ). and further, I am in the above cycle "while i_jac_shape<=(matrix_jac_np.shape[0]-1)" I substitute its value instead of the variable:

```
    jac_i=jac_i.subs(value_vector_var_new)
```

with replacement in the original sympy matrix = matrix_jacobian :

```
    matrix_jacobian[i_jac_shape,:]=jac_i[0,:]
```

on this, the above cycle ends.

2. convert sympy matrix = matrix_jacobian to numpy matrix :

   ```
    matrix_jacobian_analitic_view=np.array(matrix2numpy(matrix_jacobian), dtype='float32')
   ```

as a result , having the numerical jacobian calculation time ~= 37 seconds on the first iteration and numerical jacobian calculation time ~= 10 seconds on each next iteration , using the above code gave the calculation time ~=2.0-2.5 seconds .

P.S. one very curious story surfaced some time ago:
let the following set of variables be in the symbolic Jacobian:

```
    vector_var_jacobian=[T1,T2,T3,y1,y2,y3]
```

and the vector of values for these variables is (for example) :

```
    vector_var_value=[1,2,15,10,5,4,3,6,7,8]
```

vector_var_value specified on the variable set

```
    vector_var_system_equations=[T0,T1,T2,T3,y0,y1,y2,y3,y4]
```

and now if, without preliminary action, do the operation :

```
    value_vector_var_new=list(zip_longest(vector_var_jacobian,vector_var_value, fillvalue='-'))
```

and

```
    matrix_jacobian=matrix_jacobian.subs(value_vector_var_new)
```

then instead of doing the operation .subs with the right set of values

```
    vector_var_value=[2,15,10,3,6,7]
```

for a set of variables in the Jacobian :

```
    vector_var_jacobian=[T1,T2,T3,y1,y2,y3]
```

sympy will perform the operation .subs with a set of values :

```
    vector_var_value=[1,2,15,10,5,4]
```

for a set of variables matrix in the symbolic Jacobian :

```
    vector_var_jacobian=[T1,T2,T3,y1,y2,y3]
```

naturally , having obtained the wrong Jacobian matrix ( in numerical form ) in terms of algorithmic actions .

I think that the written piece about the substitution of numbers in symbolic expressions in simpi will be useful.